# PHP: Default image demensions

Tags: php

How can i set all images that are over 604x453 px (demensions width+height) to 604x453.

If under 604x453, keep the original size.

How can I do this? I only know the way to make everything 604x453 no matter current dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User the following command:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($file_name);
```

It will return to you the dimensions and from there you can use an if statement to determine if it fits your size restrictions.